# Help with finding the dimensions of this Vector space please

Tags: linear-algebra

$$V=\{(a,b,c,d,e)T | a-b-c=0\}.$$

Can someone help me with finding the dimension of V please? And how?

I solved the equation $a=c+b$ then $c$ and $b$ are variables so we can put $b=1, c=0$ then $b=0, c=1 $, is it $2$ dimensions ? I also tried to explain it to myself as this matrix :
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c}1 & -1 & 1& 0& 0. & 0\\
0 & 0& 0& 0& 0.&   0 \\
0 & 0& 0& 0& 0.&   0\\
0 & 0& 0& 1& 0.&   0\\
0 & 0& 0& 0& 1.&   0 \end{array}\right)$$

I just had my exam , and this question was weird , I thought of $2$ dimensions since we can do $a=b+c$ and $b$ and $c$ then are variables and we can exchange them with $0$ and $1$ then $1$ and $0$ so I thought of $2$ vector basis but what about the d and $e$ are they $0$ or could also be $1$ and $0$ to form another $2$ vectors ?

Comment: please share your attempt if any.

Comment: You have a 5-dimensional vector space as ambient space and one linear equation which cuts out 1 dimension.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: I just had my exam , and this question was weird , i thought of 2 dimensions since we can do a=b+c and b and c then are variables and we can exchange them with 0 and 1 then 1 and 0 so i thought of 2 vector basis but what about the d and e are they 0 or could also be 1 and 0 to form another 2 vectors ?

Comment: You’re neglecting the fact that since $d$ and $e$ don’t appear in the equation, they can take on any value whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the linear system $$a-b-c=0$$

It is actually $$a-b-c+0d+0e=0$$

If we write out the row echelon form, there are $4$ non-pivot columns, hence the dimension should be $4$.

Note that we do not have the last two rows as stated in your matridx as that would impose the conditions that $d=0$ and $e=0$.

$a$ is determined once we decide on $b$ and $c$, so we can choose our $b$ and $c$. Also, we are free to choose our $d$ and $e$.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the equation a=c+b then c and b are variables so we can put b=1 c=0 then b=0 c=1 , is it 2 dimensions ? I also tried to explain it to myself as this matrix :
1 -1 1 0 0.  0
0  0 0 0 0.   0
0  0 0 0 0.   0
0  0 0 1 0.   0
0  0 0 0 1.   0

Comment: you should include your attempt in your post